# Theoretical maximum depth of a decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees

During my machine learning labwork, I was trying to fit a decision tree to the IRIS dataset (150 samples, 4 features). The maximum theoretical depth my tree can reach which is, for my understanding, equals to (number of sample-1) when the tree overfits the training set. So, for my training set which consists of 100 samples that would be 99. However, I am unsure what would the maximum depth be if I want to impose that **no less than 2 samples are contained in a leaf**.
Would it just be ${100 \over 2} - 1 = 49$?

Comment: Yes, your formula is correct.

Comment: Yes. And just want to add that if all of your features were categorical then max depth would have been 4.